# Installing without a disc drive

Tags: installation, boot

My HP computer doesnt have a disc drive due to it being slim line. I keep getting to the end of the download and it says I have no where to burn the Ubuntu booting file - my external hard drive is connected. Is there a way to get Ubuntu without a disc drive on windows 7?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bootable USB drive.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows